# jQuery how to swap each instance of "&" append <span> tag to each element

Tags: php, jquery

Like the title says,

I want to be able to, on page load, search through the text located inside `#wrapper`.

If there is a "`&`" I want it to have a `span` tag applied to it and a class appended to that `span`.
Ie: 
if it finds "`hello & Welcome`" 
it should end up like "`hello <span class="amp">&</span> Welcome`".

I did have some code Ive been trying but all didn't work, so pointless to include it.
Any help would be great guys thanks.

**EDIT:** have been working with

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() { 
     $("#wrapper").html( $("#wrapper").html().replace(/&amp;/g, '<span class="amp">&amp;<"+"/span>') ); 
    }); 
</script>
```

this loads with an Error in firebug telling me it isn't a function:

$ is not a function
$(document).ready(function() {

**Edit:** oops forgot to include my reference to jQuery..

this works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() { 
       $("#wrapper").html( $("#wrapper").html().replace(/&amp;/g, '<span class="amp">&amp;<"+"/span>') ); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [jquery.highlight](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html)?  It seems that it does what you want - the correct way (by searching only within textnodes, etc)

```
$("#wrapper").highlight('&');
```

A little further explanation.  Imagine the following scenario:

```
 <div id='wrapper'>This &amp; should become highlighted.  
    And a picture: <img src='momanddad.jpg' alt='Mom &amp; Dad' /></div>
```

The blanket regexp replace will catch both of those `&amp;` occurrences and return with:

```
 <div id='wrapper'>This <span class="amp">&amp;</span> should become highlighted.  
    And a picture: <img src='momanddad.jpg' alt='Mom <span class="amp">&amp;</span> Dad' /></div>
```

This is obviously going to break your img tag.  The jquery highlight plugin will avoid that.

Comment: thanks gnarf, but the issue was, that i wanted when the page loaded it checked through the html of a particular ID now (#post)
and if it comes across &amp; it will wrap it in a span tag, with the included class applied to that span. ie <span class="amp">&amp;</span>

which the above code dose,

Comment: i understand that: but you will also end up turning <img src="blah.gif" alt="Mom &amp; Dad" /> into <img src="blah.gif" alt"Mom <span class="amp">&amp;</span> Dad" /> which isn't necessarily what you want - the jquery.highlight library handles.  It only looks at "text nodes"

Answer (score 0):

For ease of reading I would re factor to;

```
var html = $("#wrapper").text().replace(/&/g,'<span class="amp">&</span>');
$("#wrapper").html(html);
```

Although I supposes that's an extra call to the DOM.

Comment: That is just completely pointless. There's no reason to set a variable if you're only going to use it once.

Comment: You're probably right, I just like things to be blindingly obvious :-)